# Can I call/execute a vb6 app inside a windows service(vb.net)?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a massive old code written in VB6. And currently I'm writing a Windows Service using VB.Net. My goal is to add the new functionality without touching the old VB6 app so I do not have to convert all the logic to VB.Net. So is that possible to include the VB6 app(.exe) inside my Windows Service and have my new logic run before and after the VB6 app?

If possible please direct me how to do so, thank you!

Comment: Yeah it will be possible,  before heading down that track though I would question a few things.  1) is this achievable running the app via a scheduled task.  2) It’s a vb6 app, completely understand the ain’t broke don’t fix it, but sometimes you can create more work for yourself trying to dodge the bullet that if you just get your head down and commit to rewrite.

Comment: If your vb6 exe has any user interaction (console app or forms UI), then the answer is pretty much no, you can't run it from a service.  Or more precisely, if you do launch it from a service, it won't (and can't) be interacting with the desktop and/or user, so it's not going to work. On the other hand, if this is an ActiveX exe, or if it just runs as a (non-interactive) console app launched via shell, then yes, you can run it from a service.

Comment: Yes, the Windows Service should run in periodic times(I'm planning it to run every 5 minutes). Actually I need to edit the VB6 code and add some new functionality but I'm not authorized to do so. The only option that I can think of is having a windows service and add my functionalities before and after calling this VB6 app.

Comment: If you're needing to add new functionality, IMO it really is time to have a very hard look at porting it over.  Also, running a console app via task schedulers is a whole heap less headaches that implementing and debugging a service

Comment: What method is used to configure & run the VB6 app today?